# Как переместить тексты(.c3-chart-texts) в другое место (d3.js c3.js)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Как переместить в другую позицию тексты(количество) которые рисуются над столбцами?
http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0719/h_1468916833_3268381_900ef9ba65.png

Мне их надо переместить в центр столбца.Как на макете. Плюс еще вывести сумму столбцов в одной категории.
http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0719/h_1468916833_8376616_1f7fe36866.png

Вот код.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {

        columns: [
           ['Мужчины', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
           ['Женщины', 50, 170, 10, 40, 182, 25]
        ],
        colors: {
        "Мужчины" : '#0e65ab', 
        "Женщины": '#4faa33'
        },
        labels: true,

        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['Мужчины','Женщины']
        ]
    },
     legend: {
        position: 'left'
    },
    grid: {
            x: {
                show: false
            },
            y: {
                show: true
            }
        },

         axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006'],

            label: {
                text: 'Года',
                position: 'outer-center'
            }
        },
        y: {
            label: {
                text: 'Количество спортсменов уличенных в допинге',
                position: 'outer-middle'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению в API такой возможность нет. Но можно после отрисовки через JS подправить чуть чуть.

Есть блок class="c3-chart-texts" в нём все тексты хранятся в блоке

```
<text class=" c3-text c3-text-0" text-anchor="middle" style="stroke:none; fill: rgb(31, 119, 180); fill-opacity: 1;"x="67.9703125"y="135.50819672131146">30</text>
```

Параметры x и y отвечают за положение. Можно таким образом попробовать опустить.